# Double line in header

Tags: header-footer, rules

I need to have double line under the header of each page where the chapter title and page number are written (except first pages of each chapter). A sample is as the following picture:

[image]

I assume it can be achieved by `fancyhdr` package, but don't know how!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example? If you know how to do one line, give us the code for a complete small document with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**package `scrlayer-scrpage`**

Here is a suggestion using package `scrlayer-scrpage`. It defines layer page styles. There you can clone the layer that inserts the `headsepline`. Then you can shift the layer a bit and change the line width.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1.5pt,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=scrheadings.head.below.line,% clone this layer
  addvoffset=2pt,% shift it down
  contents={\KOMAoptions{headsepline=.5pt}% change the line width
            \GetLayerContents{scrheadings.head.below.line}},% use the same code as headsepline
]{scrheadings.head.below.secondline}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.secondline}% add the layer to the page style

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**package `fancyhdr`**

With package `fancyhdr` you have to redefine `\headrule`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1.5pt}
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth
\vskip 2pt% 2pt between lines
\hrule\@height.5pt\@width\headwidth% lower line with .5pt line width
\vskip-\headrulewidth
\vskip-1.5pt}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! as my document language is in Persian I need to switch the location of title and page number on each page. How can I do that?

Comment: With `scrlayer-scrpage` use `\ohead{\headmark}\ihead{\pagemark}` and with `fancyhdr` use `\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\thepage} \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}`

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple way to do it using `fancyhdr` package.

Although **esdd** provided you with a great answer, I have a different way of defining `\headrule`. I believe it is simpler and will not cause any issues down the road.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

% Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

   % Header Settings
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
   \fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
   \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
   \fancyhead[CE,CO]{}


   % Footer Settings
   \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}
   \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
   \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{}

   % Redefining headrule
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand{\headrule}{\hrule height 1.5pt \vspace{2pt}\hrule height 0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

This is how to interpret the redefinition of `\headrule`:

```
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hrule height ENTER-TOP-LINE-WIDTH \vspace{ENTER-SPACING-BETWEEN-THE-LINES}\hrule height ENTER-BOTTOM-LINE-WIDTH}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just tried this with the article class and it both 1) works, and 2) is the simplest way I have seen to do this.